# Google Sheets Array Formula Sum Previous Cell in Column Referencing Itself

Tags: google-sheets, circular-dependency, array-formulas

Like the title suggests; I, for the life of me, can't seem to get a simple array formula to work without getting a circular dependency error. The basic formula is beyond simple. The formula is put into the cell directly below, in the same column (A). **=Sum(A2+1)**. When a new row is added, if I copy and paste the formula I get an automagically modified formula; =Sum(A3+1), and so on. I want to automate this, so when new rows are added, this generated number is populated by itself. Is this just NOT possible because of the way array formula works or am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Edit:

Here is a very simple sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dr9dAu2QxoS1eE-MQ20SDGdLLyJWVX4HL5-3Z42w0BA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you actually share a sample sheet of what your trying to do - I think I know the answer as ive done variations of this many times but the way your describing it is slightly confusing

Comment: I've edited my original post to include a basic sheet.

Comment: I finally was able to add the answer for you - sorry was at  work all day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this in column A just below your cell with the static number:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1+ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1"&":A"&COUNTA(B:B)-1))))
```